# Inserting a PDF File Into a LaTeX Document

Tags: errors, pdfpages

I cannot insert a PDF file into the LaTeX document with the following code. When I run the following code, I get an error message in the log file like this:

```
"! Undefined control sequence.
\@calc@post@scan ...st@scan \else \def \calc@next
{\calc@error #1}\fi \fi \f...
l.20 \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined."
```

How can I insert a PDF file into the document?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{APPENDICES}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{myfile.pdf}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{CHAPTERR}
\section{Sectionn}
 Some stuff.
\chapter{CHAPTERRR}
\section{Sectionnn}
 Other stuff.

\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\chapter{TABLESS}
\section{DATA}
\chapter{FIGURESS}
\section{CODE}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

I want the following outputs:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would help if you would say which error message you get.

Comment: I added the image of the error message in the above post.

Comment: Show the real message from the log file, not the summary of your editor.

Comment: How did you obtain that image of desired contents? Did you type by hand?

Comment: No, I didn't. When `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and `\includepdf[pages=-]{myfile.pdf}` are deleted from the above code I posted and when the remaining code is run, then the desired contents is obtained.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, finally I found the log file and added it into my post.

Comment: Now I can confirm a conflict with `pdfpages` with the line `\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}`.  In the `.toc` file we find  `\let \calc@A \calc@Acount \let \calc@B \calc@Bcount \begingroup \aftergroup \calc@B \calc@A \begingroup \aftergroup \calc@B \calc@A \afterassignment \def {\GenericError {(calc) }{Package calc Error: '\global ' invalid at this point}{See the calc package documentation for explanation.}{I expected to see one of: + - * / )}}\calc@A 0!\global \calc@A \calc@B \endgroup \global \c@tocdepth \calc@B`

Comment: @Sigur it it not `pdfpages` it is the `calc` package

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the `pdfpages` package, but it loads `calc` and that is the issue, presumably `calc` leaves `\setcounter` unrobust or whatever...

If you want to change the counter in that location just use

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
```

to prevent `\setcounter` to be expanded prematurely. A lot of macros need protection when used in `\addtocontents`

Comment: Finally, an answer.... since last night I was thinking on it.

Comment: @Sigur it also helps taking a look inside the `.toc` or `.aux` files, then it is easy to see when something is expanded prematurely.